# Bamboo can not work

Tags: php, bamboo

I am installing Bamboo,but it can not work,I installed it according to the documentation.
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/installing-bamboo-on-windows-289276813.html

Is there any other steps to do except the installing guide?

**1. Check supported platforms**

```
OS:windows 10 x64
```

**2. Check your version of Java**

```
C:\Program Files\Bamboo\bin>java -version
java version "1.8.0_74"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_74-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.74-b02, mixed mode)
```

**3. Check that Windows can find Java**

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath
```

**4. Check permissions**

```
windows admin
```

**5. Download Bamboo**

```
no error
```

**6. Start Bamboo!**

```
C:\Program Files\Bamboo\bin>start-bamboo.bat /fg

Bamboo Server Edition
   Version : 5.10.2


If you encounter issues starting or stopping Bamboo Server, please see the Troubleshooting guide at https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Installing+Bamboo+on+Windows

The JRE_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program

C:\Program Files\Bamboo\bin>
```

Finally,access http://localhost:8085/
it can not open the page.

PS:I use Nginx.

Comment: Check your config file. are you using port 8085? Are you sure it is not blocked or being used by any other application?

Answer (score 2):

> The JRE_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
>   This environment variable is needed to run this program

Looks like you need to set JRE_HOME or JAVA_HOME before starting.

Answer (score 0):

To check if your JAVA_HOME variable is set correctly:

> echo %JAVA_HOME%